# Hibernate delete referencing records after update of the owning record in a @ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need some advice on how to properly configure a unidirectional many-to-one relationship with with JPA.

I have an entity called `ScheduleEntry`. Schedule entries need to know their parent schedule entry, but a parent schedule entry doesn't need to know its child entries. For that reason `ScheduleEntry` looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class ScheduleEntry {
    
    [...]
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = true)
    private ScheduleEntry parent;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "schedule_entry", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"))
    @Column(name = "recurrenceNumber")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Integer> recurrences;
    
}
```

There is no `OneToMany` side of this relationship.
This works fine when creating entries, setting their parent entry and fetching entries with parent entries.
However, whenever I update a parent `ScheduleEntry` Hibernate executes a `DELETE` statement and delete all child entries of the updated `ScheduleEntry`:

```
org.hibernate.SQL: update schedule_entry set active=?, cancelled=?, capacity=?, description=?, end_time=?, parent_id=?, recurrence_number=?, recurs_until_time=?, start_time=?, title=? where id=?
org.hibernate.SQL: delete from schedule_entry where parent_id=?
```

And that's not what I want. I want that child entries keep their reference to the updated parent entry and don't get deleted. I.e. I want to prevent HIbernate from executing the `DELETE` statement. Any ideas how to achieve that?

PS: The code that executes the update:

```
public void update(DTO dto) {
    jpaRepository.save(mapper.dtoToModel(dto));
}
```

called from within a REST controller that manages the transaction scope with Spring's `@Transactional`:

```
@Transactional
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody ScheduleEntryDTO dto) {
    return super.update(id, dto);
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you first study the underlying table structure in your SQL database which Hibernate has created for you under the hood.

Comment: are you sure that entries are not re-insert after removal ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using Flyway to manage tables, Hibernate doesn't create tables in my case. That's the relevant part of the table definition:

`CREATE TABLE public.schedule_entry (
 id bigserial NOT NULL,
 parent_id int8,
 [...]
 CONSTRAINT schedule_entry_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
 CONSTRAINT parent_idfk FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES public.schedule_entry(id)
);
`

Comment: @CodeScale Yes, they're gone forever.

Comment: @BozhidarD. could you share your transactional code ? Code that applies changes and commit them

Comment: @CodeScale Sure, updated the question with two more code snippets.

Comment: Why do you use transactional here? I think it might be the one responsible for deleting of the objects. Try deleting the @Transactional annotation and then try.

Comment: @Mihsu Well, the controller method opens a transaction since it generally doesn't and shouldn't know what happens at the lower layers - the service may do other changes in DB than just updating the schedule entry record. Deleting the @Transactional didn't solve the issue and Hibernate still creates a transaction to execute the `save`:
`Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]`

Comment: My bad, it's not Hibernate that starts the transaction for the `save` method of the repository but rather Spring.

Comment: Is what you posted the actual mapping? There are no other associations that refer to `ScheduleEntry` with orphan removal that could cause this?

Comment: @ChristianBeikov Good hint - there is also one more mapping that uses `parent_id`. I edited my post above with that fragment. When I comment it out the `delete` doesn't happen. The `@ElementCollection` is used to collect a given property of all children as a set of integers. Kind of what you'd achieve with @Formula, but @Formula didn't work for collections.

Comment: Oh wow, you really shouldn't do that. This will result in quite a few more issues. Never map a table to different collections/entities that are writable. I would advise you to just map the `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")` instead and handle the rest in utility methods.